# Split dataframe by multiple columns into multiple excels

Tags: python, pandas, format

Consider the following dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Id = [1, 2, 3, 3],
        Country=['jp', 'cn', 'uk', 'uk'],
        Sales = [5, 3, 3, 4]
    ))

print(df)
   Id Country  Sales
0   1      jp      5
1   2      cn      3
2   3      uk      3
3   3      uk      4
```

I want to iterate and groupby columns `Id` and `Country`and write to excel:

```
for n, g in df.groupby(['Id', 'Country']):
    print(n)
    # `n` is the group name, which will be the country
    g.to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format(n), index = False)
```

It will create files:
`["(1, 'jp').xlsx", "(2, 'cn').xlsx", "(3, 'uk').xlsx"]`, but I want the format like: `["1-jp.xlsx", "2-cn.xlsx", "3-uk.xlsx"]`.

How can I get it in Pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack tuple to variables `a` and `b` and pass to `format` function:

```
for (a, b), g in df.groupby(['Id', 'Country']):
    print(a, b)
    # `n` is the group name, which will be the country
    g.to_excel('{}_{}.xlsx'.format(a, b), index = False)
```

Or select tuples by position by indexing:

```
for n, g in df.groupby(['Id', 'Country']):
    print(n)
    # `n` is the group name, which will be the country
    g.to_excel(f'{n[0]}_{n[1]}.xlsx'.format(n), index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for n, g in df.groupby(['Id', 'Country']):
    print(n)
    g.to_excel('{}.xlsx'.format("_".join([str(x) for x in n]), index = False)
```